# how to draw image over image in javascript (without CSS and HTML)

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I create `HTMLImageElement`(s) dynamically and I draw them on canvas

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'mypath/image.png';
context.drawImage(image, point.x, point.y); // context is a CanvasRenderingContext2D element
```

Now I want to draw another image (smaller) over `image`, still dynamically. Is it possible without help of CSS or HTML?

**EDIT**

I don't want to replace an image with another image, I want to overlap two images : the biggest one in the "background" and the smallest one in front of it. "Over" is intended as a overlapped, nor replaced.

Comment: Can't you just use drawImage again to cover the image previously drawn?

Comment: If I call again drawImage the previous image is **replaced** with the new one. I don't want to replace it, I want to draw both of them, overlapped : the biggest in the "background" and the smallest in front.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `drawImage()` with the resize parameters:

```
context.drawImage(image, point.x, point.y, wantedWidth, wantedHeight);
```

Image source can be `image` or even `context` itself.

(Also remember to use `onload` handler on the image element before attempting to draw it.)

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    img = new Image;

img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(this, -200, -200, 800, 800);
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
};

img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/RV2a28T.png";
```

```html
<canvas/>
```

Comment: @FabrizioMorello you need to make sure your image has an alpha channel. If it does have an alpha channel, then this will work (it will not clear the previous, it will draw on top of it - if you need blending, set globalAlpha to f.ex =  0.5 before drawing)

Comment: How can I test whether my image has an alpha channel?

Comment: @FabrizioMorello you can f.ex fill the canvas with a solid color, draw the image on top. If you see some of the original color then your images has alpha channel (just make sure the color is something different from what is in the image).

Comment: @FabrizioMorello added example to answer