# HTML 5 -- draw pictures on canvas pictures with an onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

At the moment I have a problem with the canvas, where I hope you guys can help me out.

My Canvas gets "onload" filled with a picture of a soccerfield. I want now to display every player in the start formation after a click on the button "Start formation", with a delay of 2 seconds.

But my code does not work and I do not know where I have my mistake hope you guys can help me out.

Code - HTML/JS:

```
<article id='canvas_field'>
    <section id='canvas_control'>
    <button id='field_button' type='button' onclick='field()'>Start    
    Formation</button>
    </section>

    <section id='canvas'>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>


<script>

  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var imageObj = new Image();
  var imageObj1 = new Image();
  var imageObj2 = new Image();
  var imageObj3 = new Image();

  imageObj.src  = 'img/canvas.png';
  imageObj1.src = 'img/Stegen-ConvertImage.jpg';
  imageObj2.src = 'img/Alba-ConvertImage.jpg';
  imageObj3.src = 'img/Pique-ConvertImage.jpg';

  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 15, 0);
  };



  function field() {



 imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj1, 40, 240);;
  };
  setTimeout(field, 2000); // Add new player every 2 seconds

  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj2, 120, 100);
  };
  setTimeout(field, 2000); // Add new player every 2 seconds


  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj3, 120, 200);
  };
  setTimeout(field, 2000); // Add new player every 2 seconds



}
  </script>
</section>
</article>
```

And here the CSS for the button:

```
button{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:calc((100% - 10px)/3);
    height: 25px;
    border:2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you click the button?  Do you get any error message in the console of your browser? (F12 in IE, Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome)  You might want to also look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172223/how-to-draw-image-over-image-in-javascript-without-css-and-html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I never have been working with the console. Error: Script terminated by timeout at:
field@file:///C:/Users/Marco/Desktop/website_marco/website_marco/index.html#Introduction_Picture:156:3